# Unable to push data to xcom in airflow

Tags: python, debian, airflow

```
from airflow.operators.python import get_current_context


context = get_current_context()
ti = context['ti']
ti.xcom_push(key="file", value = doc )
```

I have the above code in a task and doc is the data that I want to pass to xcom. Its throwing the following error stack trace :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/decorators/base.py", line 217, in execute
    return_value = super().execute(context)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 175, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 192, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/rover_ocr_pipeline.py", line 65, in retrieve
    ti.xcom_push(key="file", value = doc )
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 2294, in xcom_push
    XCom.set(
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py", line 234, in set
    value = cls.serialize_value(
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py", line 627, in serialize_value
    return json.dumps(value, cls=XComEncoder).encode("UTF-8")
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/json.py", line 176, in encode
    return super().encode(o)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/json.py", line 153, in default
    CLASSNAME: o.__module__ + "." + o.__class__.__qualname__,
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

This was working till now, I am guessing its an issue with airflow version. Previously I was using 2.3.4 , now using 2.5.0.

Airflow is running on kubernetes cluster and using airflow:2.5.0-debian-11-r11 image.

Comment: To me that seems like a typing issue, its trying to treat it like a JSON and failing. What is the data type of doc?

Comment: <class 'bytes'> , xcom is kind of like a dictionary, it has a key and value, the value here in this case is just a bytes string. It shouldn't matter what the data type of value is, isn't it?

Comment: The xcom is actually just row data with an identifier and a value. When pushing to xcom it will try to convert objects to a string for storage and here it looks like its trying to convert your bytes using json.dumps and failing:
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py", line 627, in serialize_value
    return json.dumps(value, cls=XComEncoder).encode("UTF-8")
Try converting the doc to a string before passing to xcom and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: Hey @TevettGoad that seems to work now, weird how it was able to store bytes string in xcom in the last version of airflow. The problem that I am facing now is a decoding issue when I read the file from s3 -  ```utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte ```

Comment: Using base64 to encode decode bytes, passing base64 encoded string to xcom, working now, thanks @TevettGoad

Comment: Hey since my comments helped, could you select my summarized answer as the answer to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from comments to an actual answer, see above comments for full conversation

XCOM tries to convert everything to a string before storing in the XCOM tables. In this case since bytes is a class, it was trying to serialize it which isn't possible. Converting the bytes to a normal string by base64 encoding the bytes allowed for it to be stored in xcom.

While probably not worth the effort for just this case, this could be handled automatically by creating a custom xcom backend that accurately detects when dealing with byte strings and performs the conversion behind the scenes.